# Parent POM vs Super POM - are they same?

Tags: java, maven

I want to understand if Parent POM and Super POM are same or are there still differences.

Take below maven poms, I declare a parent pom as below:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>deps</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>    
                   <!-- not relevant for this question -->
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.12</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now I declare a child pom as below:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>deps2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
       <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
       <artifactId>deps</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
                           <!-- not relevant for this question -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now `deps` is the parent pom for `deps2`. I am not sure if I can also call `deps` as super pom for `deps2`.

Which of the below inheritance hierarchy is correct

1. dep2 --> deps ***end*** (NO Maven provided super pom)
2. dep2 --> deps --> Maven provided super pom ***end***

Comment: The super POM is basically `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- that answers everthing. ++100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2, because **all** models implicitly inherit from the [Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html).

`deps` is a `parent` for `deps`, but not the Super POM.
This is according to the definitions on the website.

What is more ... if you inspect the effective POM, you will see that it will always inherit from the Super POM on the MVN website.

Comment: for the reference ++1

Comment: If you accept the answer, can you mark it as accepted ? :)

Comment: `if you inspect the effective POM, you will see that it will always inherit from the Super POM` -  what signs to look for.  If i have overridden the `<distributionManagement>`, 
    `<repository>` etc i.e all of the parent pom tags, can i still find signs of super pom.

Comment: I guess its exactly like inheritance with classes. All classes in Java inherit from Object, but any behaviour can be overriden. Does this change the fact that they still inherit from Object at its core ? No, it does not.

Comment: that sets it in concrete once again. thanks